# How to dump JSON file into mongodb using Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

First of all this hasn't been asked before or if I asked there wasn't any answer provided so I am opening this new thread.

I need best way to dump a JSON file in mongodb. There could be multiple ways but I am looking for ways which gives good performance.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with pymongo. All you have to do is provide a list of dicts to insert_many.

```
mongoClient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://%s:%s@host:port"% (username,password))
mongoClientDB = mongoClient['database-name']
collection = mongoClientDB['collection-name']
collection.insert_many(listOfDicts, ordered=False)
```